# How to Un-enroll Enterprise from EMM

Tags: android-management-api

We have have been writing our own EMM solution and successfully created and enrolled device in an enterprise. However, we are unable to un-enroll enterprise by calling this API: https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/v1/enterprises/unenroll

The above API throws an exception that reads:

```
No enterprise was found for the given id. [404]
```

However, we are able to see the enterprise using this link: [play.google.com/work](https://play.google.com/work)
and can un-enroll the enterprise by going into Admin Settings.

Is there any way we can delete the enterprise by calling the above mentioned API.

Answer (score 0):

The [API](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/v1/enterprises/unenroll) you have mentioned only works for enterprises created via [Play EMM API](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api). This API unenrolls the enterprise from your EMM but does not actually delete it.

For both [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management) and Play EMM API, the only way to actually delete an enterprise is navigating to https://play.google.com/work/adminsettings and clicking on `Delete Organization`.